# Stacking C++ code working fine, but getting "glibc detected" at the end of running the code

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm currently working with "stacking" in my databases class and am having an issue with "*** glibc detected ***". From what I understand, it's an issue with either accessing memory that doesn't exist or memory leaking from some other source. I've gone through it several times and I can't see where any memory is being leaked, etc.

Our assignment is to create a dynamic stacking program.

My code consists of three files, but I'll compile them all into a single cpp:

```
//#include <dstack.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class DStack
{
    private:
    int *p;
    int *t;
    int length;

public:
    DStack();
    ~DStack();

    void push(int);
    int pop();
    void display();
};

DStack::DStack()
{
    length=0;
    cout<<"Stack has been created!"<<endl;
    p=new int[length];
}

DStack::~DStack()
{
     delete [] p;
}

void DStack::push(int elem)
{
    t = new int[length+1];
    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        t[i] = p[i];
    }
    p = t;
    p[length] = elem;
    delete [] t;
    length++;
    cout<<length;

}
int DStack::pop()
{
    t = new int[length-1];
    int ret = p[length-1];
    for ( int i = 0; i < length-1; i++ )
    {
        t[i] = p[i];
    }
    p = t;
    delete [] t;
    length--;
    return ret;
}

void DStack::display()
{
    cout<<length<<": ";
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    cout<<p[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}

//main.cpp
//#include <dstack.h>

int main() 
{
cout<<"Enter a size for stack : ";
DStack s1;

    s1.push(1);
    s1.display();
    s1.push(2);
    s1.push(3);
    s1.push(4);
    s1.push(5);
    s1.display();
    s1.pop();
    s1.display();
    s1.pop();
    s1.display();
    s1.pop();
    s1.display();
    s1.pop();
    s1.display();
    s1.pop();
    s1.display();


}
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!
The code seems to work fine as well, just that one error...

Comment: If you dynamically allocate and deallocate something a single function, you definitely shouldn't be using dynamic allocation.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Unless the something you need to use in that single function is likely to be larger than your stack frame would be happy with... But yeah, in this case it's probably not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `push` the code

```
p = t;
p[length] = elem;
delete [] t;
```

deletes the new array and leaks the old one.  You need to do

```
delete [] p;
p = t;
p[length] = elem;
```

instead.

A similar error exists in `pop`.  You might find it easier to not reallocate here and just use less of your array instead.  If you do this, you'll also need to store a `size` member and change `push` to only reallocate when `size == length`

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem in `push`:

```
p = t;
p[length] = elem;
delete [] t;
```

Since t equals p there, you are deleting the memory you just allocated, and then you access the deleted memory. I guess you meant `delete[] p` before `p = t`